# How to get number of pixels between two points in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Knowing two plotted data points on a series in Highcharts, how do I get the number of pixels between them?

Answer (score 1):

In series data you can find: `chart.series[0].data[0].plotX` so to get distance between two points, use: `chart.series[0].data[5].plotX - chart.series[0].data[0].plotX`